# How do I access the Binding of Isaac soundtrack?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I recently bought the Binding of Isaac + soundtrack.

...so how do I actually access the soundtrack?

The soundtrack shows up when I `view downloadable content` via steam, and it shows that I own it in the steam [store](http://store.steampowered.com/app/113203/)... but trying to "play now", steam boots up the game, not the soundtrack, taking me to the main menu - and I cannot find the DLC under 'options' or 'collections', so... where's mah music?

Comment: Protip: Don't buy soundtracks via Steam.

Comment: @GnomeSlicE Ironically, I got it included in one of the Game Music Bundles, so I own it twice now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The music files are located in whatever drive you installed Steam on, then this path:

`\Steam\steamapps\common\the binding of isaac\The Binding of Isaac Soundtrack`

Your files should be there and ready to play! Alternatively, you can go to the steam client and look under library > music, and see all the purchased soundtracks you own.

If you're on a Mac you'll find that path in `[Home]/Library/Application Support/Steam`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where it is on Mac OSX?

Comment: @Joe On the Mac, open a Finder window and press Command+Shift+G (or select Go > Go to Folder...). Enter "~/Library/Application Support/Steam/" (without the quotes) in the text field and press Enter. Your SteamApps folder will be in this folder.