# Binding of Isaac soundtrack

Tags: steam, the-binding-of-isaac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access the Binding of Isaac soundtrack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31697/how-do-i-access-the-binding-of-isaac-soundtrack)

I found the soundtrack but how do I play it it says .ncf or something...

If you know how to play it thanks I need to know how to play it on windows xp and Macintosh.

Comment: If you found .ncf files, you didn't find the soundtrack. They're Steam meta files of some description.

Comment: Did you purchase the soundtrack?  If not, you're not going to be able to pull it out of the Steam install very easily, if at all.